# How to copy content of one folder to another in windows with jenkins

Tags: windows, bash, jenkins, operating-system

I am trying to copy files from one folder to another in windows with jenkins.

Build script is as follows:
    `xcopy /s /Y "$WORKSPACE\\artifacts\\*.*" "$WORKSPACE\\publish-output"`

Console Output: Invalid number of parameters

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "windows" ? 
I assume the jenkins server is on Windows OS or the slave node is a windows os.
At the same time you have tagged "bash" Do you mean "batch" ?
Referring to $Workspace is not windows style either, you should be using %workspace%
An example:

- Create a freestyle job
- Restrict it to run on windows slave if the
  master is not Windows.
- Use build step "Execute Windows batch command"
- Try the command like:

  xcopy /s /Y %WORKSPACE%\dir1*.* %WORKSPACE%\dir2.

This should work.